# Liquibase generates type LONGBLOB in MySQL for BINARY(16) when moving to SpringBoot 1.3

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

Something very unexpected happened when I moved my Springboot web app from version 1.2.6 to 1.3.1.

I'm using Liquibase 3.4.2 to initialize my database, and fields declared in XML change log as '`BINARY(16)`' are created in the database as '`LONGBLOB`' (MySQL).

Fields are declared as in the example below:

```
 <createTable tableName="administrativeunit">
            <column name="id" type="BINARY(16)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
```

I'm using MySQL and HSQLDB (app supports both DBs), and it happens in both of them.

The curious part is that, if I move it back to Spring-boot 1.2.6, the fields are declared as expected (BINARY(16)).

Does anyone have any tip on how to overwrite this feature or make it works?

**UPDATE:** It seems to be a problem in the liquibase version pointed by Springboot. In my pom.xml liquibase was declared as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So, when I upgraded to SpringBoot 1.3.1, it automatically loaded Liquibase 3.4.2, which has the problem mentioned above. So I forced my pom.xml to use the previous version by specifying the version, like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

I see that as a workaround. Probably it is a bug in Liquibase, but springboot team could reference liquibase lib to a working version, and not 3.4.2.

Comment: Don't look at Spring Boot too much but rather at the dependencies that were upgraded in the process. Hibernate or Liquibase upgrade?

Comment: Actually I noticed that when upgrading springboot to 1.3, it also upgrades liquibase to 3.4.2. So probably the problem is in this version of liquibase. I'll update my answer

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll I upgraded to springboot 1.3.1 and forced my pom.xml to load liquibase 3.3.5 (the one referenced in springboot 1.2.6) and now it is working again. I don't know where it is done, but probably it is better to change the version of liquibase referenced by springboot. Just in case. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's a reasonable course of action. How about reporting the issue on the liquibase tracker to better understand what is going on? If you want to upgrade at some point, you may be stuck with the same issue again. Spring Boot shouldn't hide that IMO.

Comment: Could that be your issue? https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2531

Comment: Yes... This is my issue. I'd better wait for Liquibase 3.5.0 so. Because I use PK in my tables as BINARY (mapped to UUID in Java), this becomes a huge problem. Hopefully next springboot version the Liquibase 3.5.0 is already released. Thanks Stephane.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stephane Nicoll in his comments, it is a bug in version 3.4.2:

http://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2531

So, if you hit this bug in version 1.3.x of SpringBoot, force your application to use a previous version of Liquibase. In my case, it works with version 3.3.5, just adding the following change to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```